# Google places auto complete locale

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

hi i am trying to use the google places Api auto complete, now the results language is the same as the systems, even when i am trying to override the locale to other language the result is the same

Comment: You need to change the system's language in settings. Changing locale may not work. Can you further explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes it's exactly what i wrote, i want the results language to be same as my app language because my app language can be changed by user.